# How to create a button that can exit the application and restart the system when clicked in a Cocoa Application?

Tags: swift, macos, button, exit, restart

Our current application needs to reboot the system and exit the application cleanly on a button click however once either of the code runs i.e. code to restart or code to exit app , the other code will not run.Our application currently reloads after the reboot since it is not close properly before the system reboot.
 Button code which needs to restart and exit app:

```
@IBAction func exit2(sender: AnyObject) {
        let task = NSTask()
        let pipe = NSPipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
       //Code to reboot the system 
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash/"
        task.arguments = ["-c", "osascript -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to restart'"]

        let file:NSFileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading

        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()

        let data =  file.readDataToEndOfFile()
        datastring1 = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        //Code to close the application
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing to solve this?

Comment: Our application isn't exiting cleanly before rebooting the system. So it launches again after the reboot

Comment: You should take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25259343/4200050)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func restartAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString {
                NSLog("restart \(path)")
                _ = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/bin/open", arguments: [path])
                NSApp.terminate(self)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.